# Как сделать чтобы QFileDialog видел только файлы без расширения?

Tags: qt

```
QString str = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0, "Открыть файл", "", "Text files (*.)");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
QString str = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0, "Открыть файл", "", "");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем как то не выходит, а хотелось бы чтоб, был виден только файл nav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как сделать чтобы QFileDialog видел только файлы без расширения?

Вообще говоря, разумными средствами — ни как.

> В общем както не выыходит, а хотелось бы чтоб, был виден только файл nav

как-то так:

```
QString str = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0, "Открыть файл", "", "Nav files (nav)");
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но это случаем не привязка к имени ???   мне бы просто хотелось чтоб была привязка  к без форматным файлам.

Comment: @timob256, тогда из коробки — ни как — грамматика glob-выражений не позволяет такого задать... если очень-очень хочется, то можно, например, подсунуть диалогу свою proxy-модель (смотри `QFileDialo::setProxyModel ()`).

Comment: `if(fileName.contains(".", Qt::CaseInsensitive) == true)  { ui->textEdit->setText("Ошибка! Файл должен быть без расширения!"); return false; }`  такую хреньку добавил, а так видит все файлы.

Comment: @timob256, плохая практика... проще позволить пользователю выбирать что угодно... в конце концов,ДОС мёртв и расширение — всего лишь часть имени ...